# Twitter Bootstrap . I cant open my modal manually

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap

## Here is my js code :

```
$('#myModal').modal('show');
```

Here is my modal div :
     [same to the guide](http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/javascript.html#modals)

Comment: Please add your markup

Comment: You can see it in the link with the title live demo sir !

Answer (score 0):

You need to add button event, like this:

```
<a href="#myModal" role="button" class="btn" data-toggle="modal">Launch demo modal</a>
```

Comment: nope sir , i want it to show by not clicking the button !